# SQL: Sub Query to filter the result of a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT SUM(imps.[Count]) AS A , COUNT (imps.Interest_Name) AS B, ver.Vertical_name
FROM Impressions imps
INNER JOIN Verticals ver 
ON imps.Campaign_id = ver.Campaign_id
WHERE ver.Vertical_name = 'Retail' OR ver.Vertical_name = 'Travel'
GROUP BY imps.Interest_Name, ver.Vertical_name;
```

The above query returns a record as :

```
 A  B   Vertical_name
 6  6   Retail
 3  2   Retail
 7  1   Travel
13  10  Travel
```

I want to modify this query to get a result such as :

```
 A  B   Vertical_name
 9  8   Retail
 20 11  Travel
```

That is further grouping by the vertical name and taking the SUM of the colums A and B. I guess this has to be done by a sub query buy not sure how?

Comment: Please share your original table.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. please tag the rdbms which you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by `vertical_name` and remove the `imps.Interest_Name` from your `GROUP BY` since you doing a `COUNT (imps.Interest_Name)` on it.

```
SELECT SUM(imps.[Count]) AS A , COUNT (imps.Interest_Name) AS B, ver.Vertical_name
FROM Impressions imps
INNER JOIN Verticals ver 
ON imps.Campaign_id = ver.Campaign_id
WHERE ver.Vertical_name = 'Retail' OR ver.Vertical_name = 'Travel'
GROUP BY ver.Vertical_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

your doing group by two column i.e imps.Interest_Name, ver.Vertical_name.
I modified your SQL i think these will useful to you.

```
SELECT SUM(imps.[Count]) AS A , COUNT (imps.Interest_Name) AS B, ver.Vertical_name
    FROM Impressions imps
    INNER JOIN Verticals ver 
    ON imps.Campaign_id = ver.Campaign_id
    WHERE ver.Vertical_name = 'Retail' OR ver.Vertical_name = 'Travel'
    GROUP BY  ver.Vertical_name;
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT SUM(imps.[Count]) AS A , COUNT (imps.Interest_Name) AS B, ver.Vertical_name
FROM Impressions imps
INNER JOIN Verticals ver 
ON imps.Campaign_id = ver.Campaign_id
WHERE ver.Vertical_name = 'Retail' OR ver.Vertical_name = 'Travel'
GROUP BY  ver.Vertical_name;
```